# How to access the procedure that return setof refcursor from PostgreSQL in Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, ref-cursor

Need to access a procedure that return setof refcursor from PostgreSQL.

I am able to access the first object but not rest of object not rest of objects.

```
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    try (CallableStatement proc = 
             con.prepareCall("{ ? = call usp_sel_article_initialdata_new1() }")) {
        proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER);
        proc.execute();
        ResultSet results = (ResultSet) proc.getObject(1); 
        while (results.next()) {
            System.out.println("Result Id" + results.getString(1));
            System.out.println("Results Name" + results.getString(2));
    }
```

This give me the first refcursor values but when i try to use second refcursor it give me error
I use this line:

```
proc.registerOutParameter(2, Types.OTHER);
```

It is giving errors . Also tried:

```
proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.REF);
```

This also not work.
Procedure Example is:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION usp_sel_article_initialdata_new1()
    RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS
    $BODY$
    Declare swv_refcur refcursor;
    swv_refcur2 refcursor;
    DECLARE r record;
    BEGIN

    open SWV_RefCur for Select OM.opID as ID,OM.OperatorName as Name from operator
    AS OM (OPid bigint,OperatorName character varying(100),status boolean)
    where OM.status = true 
    order By OperatorName;
    return next SWV_RefCur;

    open SWV_RefCur2 for Select CC.cirid as ID,CC.cirnm as Name from  circle 
    AS CC (cirid bigint,cirnm character varying(100),status boolean)
    where Status = true and cirid not in(28,31) 
    order by cirnm;
    return next SWV_RefCur2;
```

Please help me how to access second object.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  But then it will return this :       <unnamed portal 1>
<unnamed portal 2>  I am not able to use this return values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`returns setof refcursor` means you get a regular `ResultSet` where each "row" contains *another* ResultSet when calling `getObject()`:

The following works for me:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from usp_sel_article_initialdata_new1()");
if (rs.next())
{
  // first result set returned
  Object o = rs.getObject(1);
  if (o instanceof ResultSet)
  {
    ResultSet rs1 = (ResultSet)o;
    while (rs1.next())
    {
       int id = rs1.getInt(1);
       String name = rs1.getString(2);
       .... retrieve the other columns using the approriate getXXX() calls
    }
  }
}

if (rs.next()) 
{
  // process second ResultSet 
  Object o = rs.getObject(1);
  if (o instanceof ResultSet)
  {
    ResultSet rs2 = (ResultSet)o;
    while (rs2.next())
    {
       ......
    }
  }
}
```

From within `psql` you can also use `select * from usp_sel_article_initialdata_new1()` you just need to use `FETCH ALL` afterwards. See the manual for an example: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN59018

```
postgres=> select * from usp_sel_article_initialdata_new1();
 usp_sel_article_initialdata_new1
----------------------------------
 <unnamed portal 1>
 <unnamed portal 2>
(2 rows)

postgres=> fetch all from "<unnamed portal 1>";
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)

postgres=> fetch all from "<unnamed portal 2>";
 ?column?
----------
        2
(1 row)

postgres=>
```

(I created a dummy function for the above example that only returns a single row with the value `1` for the first cursor and `2` for the second cursor)

**Edit**:

In order for this to work, this needs to be run inside a transaction. Therefor autocommit must be turned off:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Comment: I have use this code it is giving error at this line:    Object o = rs.getObject(1);  "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 1>" does not exist"

Comment: @pankaj369 It worked for me using Postgres 9.3 and the current 9.3 JDBC driver (build 1102). Which Postgres version and driver version are you using?

Comment: @ If i print it string value like this : if (rs.next()) {
           System.out.println("first result set"+rs.getString(1));   Then it is printing this: "first result set<unnamed portal 1>"

Comment: You should ***not*** use `getString()` you *have* to use `getObject()` and then cast it to a `ResultSet` as I have done in my code.

Comment: I was using your code. By printing i was just checking what it is returning. After removing System.out.println also it is giving same error. And i was using old jar but now i have changed it to 9.3 JDBC driver and i am using Postgres9.3 .But still same error exist.

Comment: @pankaj369 then I don't know what's wrong in your system. It does work for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60815/discussion-between-pankaj369-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Comment: It solved my problem . Just add one more line before creating connection.   connection.setAutoCommit(false); Thanks a lot.

Comment: @pankaj369: thanks for the feedback. I never use autocommit, that's why I didn't realize this was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When i call stored procedures i use EntityManager.
Below I attached simple example:

```
//StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("[database_name].[schema_name].[procedure_name]");
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("[Mydatabase].[dbo].[process_user]");

//registering INPUT parameters
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("Id",Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("Name",String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("UserType",Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);

//registering OUTPUT parameters
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("ErrorCode",Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("ErrorMessage",String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

//setting INPUT parameters
storedProcedure.setParameter("Id", 12345);
storedProcedure.setParameter("Name", "Mick");
storedProcedure.setParameter("UserType", 1);

//executing procedure
storedProcedure.execute();

//getting results 
Integer errorCode = (Integer) storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("ErrorCode");
String errorMessage = (String) storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("ErrorMessage");
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I havent use hibernate and in this project also i am not using hibernate so it is not possible for me to implement this code. My main problem is that i am not able to access the second cursor in procedure that return setof refcursor.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in following version

springframework-version :- 4.2.1.RELEASE

hibernate.version:- 5.0.1.Final

postgresql.version :- 9.1-901-1.jdbc4

```
// Call the stored procedure
ProcedureCall procedureCall =  getSession().createStoredProcedureCall("get_all_matching_email_profile");

// Register the output parameter, postgres support ref_cursor as first parameter only, so don't change it
procedureCall.registerParameter(1, void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);

// Inpur parameters
procedureCall.registerParameter(2, BigDecimal.class, ParameterMode.IN);
procedureCall.registerParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
procedureCall.getParameterRegistration(2).bindValue(companyId);
procedureCall.getParameterRegistration(3).bindValue(tempArray[i]); 

 // Execute the procedure and get the result
ProcedureOutputs procedureOutputs = procedureCall.getOutputs();
ResultSetOutput resultSetOutput = (ResultSetOutput)procedureOutputs.getCurrent();
List results = resultSetOutput.getResultList();

log.info("The result is "+results.size());

for(Integer j=0;j<results.size();j++) {
Object[] objects = (Object[]) results.get(j);
log.info("The result is "+objects.length);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Connection conn = DBConnection.getNMSDBConnection();    
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
             CallableStatement properCase = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call data.temperature_raw_data( ?,?,?,? ) }") ;
                 properCase.registerOutParameter(1, Types.REF_CURSOR);
                 properCase.setLong(2, startDate);
                 properCase.setLong(3, endDate);
                 properCase.setString(4, deviceIp);
                 properCase.setString(5, customers);
                 properCase.execute();
                ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) properCase.getObject(1);
                while (rs.next()) 
                {
                    HashMap<String, Object> record = new HashMap<>();                       
                    record.put("date", rs.getTimestamp(1));
                    record.put("nodeIp", rs.getString(2));
                    record.put("avg", rs.getDouble(3));
                    records.add(record);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want to write a java code which will call PostgreSQL Stored procedure where 
there is an INOUT refcursor.
PostgreSQL SP:

 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  Read_DataDetails(INOUT  my_cursor REFCURSOR = 'rs_resultone')
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 AS $$                                                    
 BEGIN
 OPEN my_cursor FOR Select * from MyData;      
 END;
 $$;

 corresponding java code will be:

connection = getConnection(your connection parameter);
if (connection != null) {
connection.setAutoCommit(false); // This line must be written just after the 
//connection open otherwise it will not work since cursor will be closed immediately. 
String readMetaData = "CALL Read_DataDetails(?)";
callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(readMetaData);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.REF_CURSOR);
callableStatement.execute();
rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);
if (rs != null) {
    while (rs.next()) {
                 <Your Logic>
                }//end while
            }//end if

}//end if
```