# How to create function/procedure in pl/pgsql returning refcursor and totalRow?

Tags: java, postgresql, plpgsql

In `pl/pgsql`, I want to create function/procedure to return the result list(returned records) of table and totalRecord, so I create this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_LIST_NOTIFY(    
        -- Cursor param
             out PO_Cursor refcursor, -- return Resutlset
             out PO_ErrorCode   VARCHAR,
             out PO_ErrorDesc    VARCHAR,
             OUT PO_TotalRow        VARCHAR
     )
      as
      $$
    declare
      -- Variable Declare
       vSqlSel               VARCHAR(20000); -- Sql select
      -- END Variable Declare
    begin       
      PO_ErrorCode := 'CODE';
      PO_ErrorDesc := 'MSG_DESC';

       vSqlSel := 'SELECT ID, TITLE ' ||
                  ' FROM USER_NOTIFICATION ';

       raise info 'sql select : %', vSqlSel;

        -- open cursor
       OPEN PO_Cursor for execute vSqlSel;
        EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM USER_NOTIFICATION' INTO PO_TotalRow;
       EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN             
        PO_ErrorCode := 'COMMONERROR_CODE';
        PO_ErrorDesc := substr(SQLERRM,1,200);

          RAISE;

    END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
     -- END GET_LIST_NOTIFY
```

But when I call this function, the returned result is:

```
- refcursor is "<unnamed portal 1>"
- PO_ErrorCode  is "CODE"
- PO_ErrorDesc  is "MSG_DESC"
- PO_TotalRow   is "10"
```

So, I can't use the refcursor to retrieve and display the record data in `java`. How can I resolve this problem?

In oracle pl/sql I can write like:

```
PROCEDURE GET_LIST_NOTIFY(
        -- Fields param
             PI_USERNAME    IN   VARCHAR2,
        -- END Fields param

        -- Cursor param
             PO_Cursor        OUT  REF CURSOR,
              PO_TotalRow     OUT   VARCHAR2,
             PO_ErrorCode   OUT VARCHAR2,
             PO_ErrorDesc   OUT VARCHAR2
     )
      AS
          -- Variable Declare
       vSqlSel               VARCHAR2(20000); -- Sql select
          -- END Variable Declare

    BEGIN

      PO_ErrorCode := 'SUCCESS_CODE';
      PO_ErrorDesc := 'SUCCESS_MSG';

       vSqlSel := 'SELECT ID, TITLE ' ||
                  ' FROM USER_NOTIFICATION ';

       dbms_output.put_line('sql select :' || vSqlSel);
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT count(*) FROM USER_NOTIFICATION' INTO PO_TotalRow;
        -- open cursor
       OPEN PO_Cursor FOR
            vSqlSel;


       EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          IF PO_Cursor%ISOPEN THEN
            CLOSE PO_Cursor;
          END IF;

        PO_ErrorCode := 'COMMONERROR_CODE';
        PO_ErrorDesc := substr(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace || ' ' ||
                        SQLERRM,1,200);

          RAISE;

    END;
     -- END GET_LIST_NOTIFY
```

In my java code, I call this "get_list_notify" function like this:

```
            RowMapper rowMapper = new RowMapper() {
                @Override
                public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownum) throws SQLException {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    OptionDTO dto = new OptionDTO();
                    try {

                        dto.setValue(Utils.validateHTMLParam(rs.getString(1).trim(), false));
                        dto.setText(Utils.validateHTMLParam(rs.getString(2).trim(), false));

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        ErrorHelper.PrintStackTrace(this.getClass().getName(), e, "DataProcessing.getDrowdownData2.OptionMapper.mapRow error : ");
                    }

                    return dto;
                }
            };

           SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(DBConnector.getConnection())
                        .withFunctionName(procedureName).withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
                Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap();
                for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {
                    simpleJdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter(key, parameters.get(key).getType()));
                    if(Utils.isNummericOracleType(parameters.get(key).getType()) && parameters.get(key).getData() != null)
                        params.put(key, new BigDecimal(parameters.get(key).getData().toString()));
                    else
                        params.put(key, parameters.get(key).getData());
                }

                simpleJdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlOutParameter("PO_Cursor", Oid.REF_CURSOR, rowMapper));
                simpleJdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlOutParameter("PO_ErrorCode", Oid.VARCHAR));
                simpleJdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlOutParameter("PO_ErrorDesc", Oid.VARCHAR));

                Map<String, Object> map = simpleJdbcCall.execute(params);
```

But when execute, **simpleJdbcCall.execute(params)** raise exception as follow:

```
[err] -----org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call get_list_notify(?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [34000]; error code [0]; ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 1>" does not exist; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 1>" does not exist
[err] --------------- At classes : ---------------
[err] ----- at com.bidv.bidvwas.common.DataProccessing.getDrowdownData(DataProccessing.java:399)
```

How can I convert pl/pgsql exactly and resolve call function from java. I use springjdbc-4.2.5 and postgres 10.4

Answer (score 1):

Your code is little bit strange (it is too much strange - there are almost all antipatterns that I know :) - in one example). You try to join things that should be separated, and you are try to use stored procedures badly. Usually procedures should not to supply views (Not in all databases without MSSQL). With procedures your code should be more readable, not less.

You are miss command `FETCH`. You should to use it for `<unnamed portal>`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fx(par text, INOUT r refcursor, OUT result integer)
 RETURNS record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  result := 10;
  OPEN r FOR SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE relname LIKE par;
END;
$function$
```

```
postgres=# SELECT fx('pg_c%', 'my_name_for_cursor');
┌─────────────────────────┐
│           fx            │
╞═════════════════════════╡
│ (my_name_for_cursor,10) │
└─────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# FETCH 10 FROM my_name_for_cursor;
┌───────────────────────────────────┬──────────────┬─────────┬───────────┬──────────┬───────┬─────────────┬─────────────
│              relname              │ relnamespace │ reltype │ reloftype │ relowner │ relam │ relfilenode │ reltablespac
╞═══════════════════════════════════╪══════════════╪═════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪═════════════
│ pg_cast_oid_index                 │           11 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │        2660 │             
│ pg_cast_source_target_index       │           11 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │        2661 │             
│ pg_class_oid_index                │           11 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │           0 │             
│ pg_class_relname_nsp_index        │           11 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │           0 │             
│ pg_class_tblspc_relfilenode_index │           11 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │           0 │             
│ pg_collation_name_enc_nsp_index   │           11 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │        3164 │             
│ pg_collation_oid_index            │           11 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │        3085 │             
│ pg_constraint_conname_nsp_index   │           11 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │        2664 │             
│ pg_constraint_conrelid_index      │           11 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │        2665 │             
│ pg_constraint_contypid_index      │           11 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │        2666 │             
└───────────────────────────────────┴──────────────┴─────────┴───────────┴──────────┴───────┴─────────────┴─────────────
(10 rows)
postgres=# COMMIT;
```

More - you use dynamic SQL too much (command `EXECUTE`). Newer use dynamic SQL when it is not necessary. And in your example, dynamic SQL should not be used ever.

Trapping all errors is usually bad idea too. This is job for client, not for code in stored procedures. Handle only errors that you can correctly solve. All information about exception can take on client side too, and you don't need to write these obscure wrappers.

Comment: Dear @pavel stehule, tks for your response. Actually, I convert code from oracle pl/sql to postgres pl/pgsql. But it seems pl/pgsql not support "output refcursor parameter" and "output varchar parameter" together. I have updated oracle pl/sql in my post, how do I convert to pl/pgsql. Thank you so much!

Comment: @vuanhkieu you can see, Postgres allow it - there is not any problem on server side. My code is working when I changed result to varchar. The result from you ported function is correct. Btw - you original PL/SQL is buggy (partially). When you reraise a exception, then setting out parameters is useless.

Comment: Dear @PavelStehule: I call this pl/pgsql function from java application, and raise the exception [err] -----org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call get_list_notify(?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [34000]; error code [0]; ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 1>" does not exist; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 1>" does not exist. Please help me to solve this problem. I have updated code java in my post. thank u so much

Comment: @vuanhkieu - it looks like some JDBC related issue, and it is too dark area for me. Maybe the problem is in autocomit - the cursor life is limited to current transaction. If the transaction used for CALL is closed, then cursor is closed too.

Comment: @PavelStehule: anyway, thank so much for your support. I've followed the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718791/how-to-access-the-procedure-that-return-setof-refcursor-from-postgresql-in-java/34171439, and it seemd to solve my problem

Comment: @vuanhkieu, yes, I though so the problem is on Java side