# How to return a dynamic data type from a procedure using PostgreSQL 11?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am looking for the dynamic result set to be return from procedure as we have in SQL Server.

In the earlier version of Postgres there was not procedure till version 10, but now in 11 we do have procedures.

I tried with functions in the postgresql but we need to provide the return type for the functions. But I am looking for the result which is dynamic, I mean to say sometimes the results comes from different table with different columns list based on the conditions check.

As I saw some of the examples of procedures from [EDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/10-examples-postgresql-stored-procedures), Unable to find an example for retrieving data.

Comment: You can't really have "dynamic results" in Postgres (and I always find them scary when I see them). The closest thing you can get is to return a refcursor, but that's not easy to deal with. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718791